# sudo issues in ansible to run sudo as specific user

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I want to run this in ansible:

```
chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

The goal is to `chown vagrant:vagrant` `/home/vagrant/.kube/config`.

Now I'm unable to make this work (I already hardcoded the path for this test ($HOME is `/root` for root user of course):

I tried:

```
- name: Setup local kubeconfig
  become: true
  shell:
    cmd: |
      chown $(id -u):$(id -g) /home/vagrant/.kube/config
```

Which results in `root:root` (chown is run as root user)

I also tried

```
- name: Setup local kubeconfig
  become: true
  become_user: vagrant
  shell:
    cmd: |
      chown $(id -u):$(id -g) /home/vagrant/.kube/config
```

which results in a permission denied because it fakes

```
sudo -u vagrant chown $(id -u):$(id -g) /home/vagrant/.kube/config
chown: changing ownership of '/home/vagrant/.kube/config': Operation not permitted
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `become_method`: user vagrant must have sudo permission

```
- name: Setup local kubeconfig
  become: true
  become_user: vagrant
  become_method: sudo
  shell:
    cmd: |
      chown $(id -u):$(id -g) /home/vagrant/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the `vagrant` user in the `id` commands:

```
- name: Setup local kubeconfig
  become: true
  become_user: root
  shell:
    cmd: |
      chown $(id -u vagrant):$(id -g vagrant) /home/vagrant/.kube/config
```

(But why can't you just use `chown vagrant:vagrant`?)